# Converting Varchar 3 to int

Tags: sql, sql-server, type-conversion

When entering the very last join in my code below I get an error message that states "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '3' to data type int." (MSG 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1) Can someone please help me with this? In the one table it does have weird characters in front of the number that I am trying to join with the other number in the other table.

```
SELECT ca.fdorgunit AS Facility
, pt.fdmedrecnum AS Account
, ca.fddos AS DOS
, ad.fdaddr1 AS [Address]
, pe.fdssn AS SSN
FROM OPENQUERY (VISION, 'SELECT * FROM ci.tbcase') AS ca
LEFT JOIN OPENQUERY (VISION, 'SELECT * FROM de.tbpatient') AS pt
ON pt.id = ca.fdpatient
LEFT JOIN OPENQUERY (VISION, 'SELECT * FROM de.tbperson') AS pe
ON pt.fdperson = pe.fdid
LEFT JOIN OPENQUERY (VISION, 'SELECT * FROM de.tbaddress') AS ad
ON ad.id = pe.fdaddress
WHERE ca.fdcasestatus = 'Performed'
GROUP BY ca.fdorgunit, ca.fddos, pt.fdmedrecnum, pe.fdssn, ad.fdaddr1
```

Comment: Can you please post the data types for ad.id and pe.address?

Comment: You need to share those "weird character" rows...

Comment: You can cast pe.fdaddress to int, if it is an int value (without "weird characters"). However, if fdaddress is supposed act as an indexed foreign key, that index will no longer work (the index is for the original varchar value, not an int). You should always try to design your database to have appropriate primary and/or foreign keys on your tables.

Comment: @Eli How do I identify the data type? I am using a linked server as well.

Comment: Do you have access to the servers on which they live? What is the RDBMS type on that remote server?

Comment: @Eli ad.id is varchar 4096 pe.address is the one with the weird characters. I am not sure how to identify the data type since it's in a linked server.

Comment: Aren't they all on the same server? You are pointing to the same linked server for all 4 of them.

Comment: @Eli They are all on the same server but the one table I identified the data type is on our server. I easily opened the table columns folder. This other table is only on the linked server which I do not have access to all the table folders.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleting Characters Before Integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44960812/deleting-characters-before-integer)

Answer (score 0):

I think one of your records propabaly in pe.fdaddress is not numeric
to avoid this you better convert the integer to char
something like this

```
SELECT ca.fdorgunit AS Facility
, pt.fdmedrecnum AS Account
, ca.fddos AS DOS
, ad.fdaddr1 AS [Address]
, pe.fdssn AS SSN
FROM OPENQUERY (VISION, 'SELECT * FROM ci.tbcase') AS ca
LEFT JOIN OPENQUERY (VISION, 'SELECT * FROM de.tbpatient') AS pt
ON pt.id = ca.fdpatient
LEFT JOIN OPENQUERY (VISION, 'SELECT * FROM de.tbperson') AS pe
ON pt.fdperson = pe.fdid
LEFT JOIN OPENQUERY (VISION, 'SELECT * FROM de.tbaddress') AS ad
ON CAST(ad.id AS varchar(10)) =  CAST(pe.fdaddress AS varchar(10))
WHERE ca.fdcasestatus = 'Performed'
GROUP BY ca.fdorgunit, ca.fddos, pt.fdmedrecnum, pe.fdssn, ad.fdaddr1
```