# Deleting Characters Before Integer

Tags: sql-server, join, null, trim

pe.fdaddress has strange characters before the number. This is preventing my code from joining properly. Is there any way to remove these characters to run my code properly? The addresses results are null because of this. Thanks

```
SELECT ca.fdorgunit AS Facility
, pt.fdmedrecnum AS Account
, ca.fddos AS DOS
, pe.fddob AS DOB
, pe.fdssn AS SSN
, ad.fdaddr1 AS [Address]
FROM OPENQUERY (VISION, 'SELECT * FROM ci.tbcase') AS ca
LEFT JOIN OPENQUERY (VISION, 'SELECT * FROM de.tbpatient') AS pt
ON pt.id = ca.fdpatient
LEFT JOIN OPENQUERY (VISION, 'SELECT * FROM de.tbperson') AS pe
ON pt.fdperson = pe.fdid
LEFT JOIN OPENQUERY (VISION, 'SELECT * FROM de.tbaddress') AS ad
ON ad.id = pe.fdaddress
WHERE ca.fdcasestatus = 'Performed'
GROUP BY ca.fdorgunit, ca.fddos, pt.fdmedrecnum, pe.fdssn, pe.fddob, ad.fdaddr1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not nice to double post--you should [clarify the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44958801/converting-varchar-3-to-int).

Anywho... here is how to avoid that problem. see the change to your query. Also, I have no idea why you are using `OPENQUERY` here. You should look into [`LINKED SERVERS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine)

```
SELECT ca.fdorgunit AS Facility
, pt.fdmedrecnum AS Account
, ca.fddos AS DOS
, pe.fddob AS DOB
, pe.fdssn AS SSN
, ad.fdaddr1 AS [Address]
FROM OPENQUERY (VISION, 'SELECT * FROM ci.tbcase') AS ca
LEFT JOIN OPENQUERY (VISION, 'SELECT * FROM de.tbpatient') AS pt
ON pt.id = ca.fdpatient
LEFT JOIN OPENQUERY (VISION, 'SELECT * FROM de.tbperson') AS pe
ON pt.fdperson = pe.fdid
LEFT JOIN OPENQUERY (VISION, 'SELECT * FROM de.tbaddress') AS ad
--here is the change
ON ad.id = LEFT(SUBSTRING(pe.fdaddress, PATINDEX('%[0-9.-]%', pe.fdaddress), 8000),PATINDEX('%[^0-9.-]%', SUBSTRING(pe.fdaddress, PATINDEX('%[0-9.-]%', pe.fdaddress), 8000) + 'X') -1)
WHERE ca.fdcasestatus = 'Performed'
GROUP BY ca.fdorgunit, ca.fddos, pt.fdmedrecnum, pe.fdssn, pe.fddob, ad.fdaddr1
```

Comment: thank you! This fixed my issue and sorry about the double post. I am fairly new and learning these guidelines of SO.

Comment: No worries @Tosh, it will come with time.